# Do I have to apply lock even though accessing concurrent dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, concurrentdictionary

I use a static concurrent dictionary in web api and it is accessed by across the users.

I am using the methods below: Are these methods all thread safe? Or do I have to add `lock()` even though it is `ConccurentDictionary`?

Basically, it is accessed by across the user then it should able to work accordingly as this dictionary contain the collection for each user and it relies on that.

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, SApp> SAppFarm= new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SApp>();    

.TryRemove(_sessionUser,out s);
.TryAdd(_sessionUser, r);
.GetOrAdd(sessionUser, application);
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety so no, no locking required on the methods you mention

Comment: From MSDN: _Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently._

Comment: Ya, its threadsafe, I went by msdn but , not sure all methods are too support it.For my case, it will only one key access per thread and add/update its value in same thread then i guess nothing to worry even change operation. Each key for separate user - request thread. and each user work for that key's object for add/edit operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ConcurrentDictionary` is it is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) is thread-safe. This includes the `TryRemove`, `TryAdd` and `GetOrAdd` methods.

Therefore no locking is required. Please keep in mind, that thread safety regards the **keys**. If you change the same **value object** for a given key in different threads, then you have to care for the thread-safety of this change operation.

Comment: ok, so, For my case, it will only one key access per thread and add/update its value in same thread then i guess nothing to worry even change operation. Each key for separate user - request thread. and each user work for that key's object for add/edit operation. Its correct, right ?

Comment: Right, you only have to consider the case if the same user (the same key) has got two or more concurrent requests (multiple threads) that simultanously change the same value object.